# How do I think of the Hom functor?

Tags: category-theory, intuition, functors, pullback

> For an object $X$ in a category $C$, there is a functor $C(-\,,X)$ from $C^{\mathrm{op}}$ to Set that assigns to each object $Z$ the set $C(Z,X)$ and to each morphism $f: Y \to Z$ the pullback $f^*$ to $f$
> $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> Y \\
> @V{f}VV \\
> Z
> \end{CD}
> \quad\mapsto \quad 
> \begin{CD}
> C(Y, X) \\
> @AA{f^*}A \\
> C(Z, X)
> \end{CD}
> $$
> (Page 10, *A categorical approach to topology*)

I am having a lot of difficulty understanding the above definition. After flipping back and forth the book, I think so I get each individual part of the definition (what the hom set is, the pull back etc), but I am unable to think of a relatable realization of it.

Could someone explain the above a bit more simply, perhaps through a metaphor?

[I'm looking for something around the lines of how Qiaochu Yuan answered this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/371949/688539)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what's confusing you about this definition (though I know that might be hard). For a very concrete example, say you have a continuous function $f : X \to Y$. Do you see how, for a continuous function $\varphi : Y \to \mathbb{R}$, we can get a new function $\varphi \circ f : X \to \mathbb{R}$? More generally composing with $f$ gives a function from $C(Y,\mathbb{R})$ to $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ sending $\varphi$ to $\varphi \circ f$. This "precomposition with $f$" works in any category, and we usually call it $f^*$. Does this example make sense?

Comment: I get the pull back and everything else @HallaSurvivor . The thing is I can't imagine this to be anything to be any concrete idea that I can relate to my life experience. For example, I can understand Functors in general as sort of analogies  , natural transformation as a nice sort of analogies between analogies etc but this one thing I am utterly stuck. It seems so there is no single thing I can relate it too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, this might be a little bit of a stretch, but here’s an attempt at an analogy that might make sense.

Your (locally small) category $\mathcal{C}$ is your city. Think of the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ as different locations around the city. There’s your home, the grocery store, your favorite dive bar, the park you walk your dog Glenn in (this is my analogy so I get to name your dog), the coffee shop you read in on the weekends, etc. For any two locations $a$ and $b$, think of $\text{hom}(a,b)$ as the set of all the different routes you could take to walk from location $a$ to location $b$.

So let’s fix a location. Say, the library. Let $L$ denote the the library. How should we think of the functor $\text{hom}(-,L)$? We can think of this functor as Google maps, in a sense. If you tell this functor some location $a$, it will spit out all the different routes you could take from $a$ to the library $L$. That is, it gives you the set of routes $\text{hom}(a,L)$.

Now what about the functors value on maps? Suppose now we have some arrow $f:a \rightarrow b$ in $\mathcal{C}$. So in the analogy, this is some specific route through your city from $a$ to $b$. By the definition of a contravariant functor, we know that $\text{hom}(f,L)$ should be a set-function from $\text{hom}(b,L)$ to $\text{hom}(a,L)$. So in the analogy, we should get a way to take in a route from $b$ to the library, and spit out a route from $a$ to the library. But we can do this easily by just first taking the pre-chosen route $f:a \rightarrow b$, and then the route from $b$ to $L$.

So in the Google maps analogy, suppose you’re at $H$ := your home, you have to run a quick errand at $S$ := the store, and then head to $L$ := the library. Finally, suppose you know exactly the route you want to take from your home to the store (call it $f$). Then Google maps would tell you all the different ways you could go from your house to the library, starting with your pre-chosen route $f$. Google is asking you to make a choice of a route from $S$ to $L$, and in return you’re getting a route from $H$ to $L$.

---

Please note that I don’t think this is a particularly good analogy. In particular, there are many other parts of category theory that are conceptually related to formal paths. This is just the best I could come up with on the fly.

Comment: Damn this is beyond what I've expected bravo

Comment: If this is what you're capable of making up on the fly I wonder what it's like if you were to sit down and think about it.  do let me know if you ever write a cat theory book

Comment: Could you explain why you don't think this is good? I think this is one of the greatest thing I have read in like a week

Comment: BTW I think a mistake at end, you mention park but initially it was home store and library

Comment: I’m glad you found this helpful! Good catch on the typo — it’s fixed. There are a few problems I see with this analogy. First, given the intersections between homotopy theory, category theory, and type theory (where “equality” is often analogized to paths between points), I feel like analogies of the form “X is like a path” are overloaded. Trying to keep all these different analogies straight can be a real hassle! Second, the contravariant hom functor is an incredibly important functor. it’s connected to sheaves, topoi, and the yoneda lemma. This analogy might make those ideas harder to get.

Comment: One other problem with this analogy is that it obscures how different the covariant and contravariant hom functors can be. In particular, since every route through a city can be “reversed” by just walking it backward, we’re implicitly assuming that our category is a groupoid. This isn’t a huge problem for the analogy, but it hides how interesting things can get. For example, suppose our category has a terminal object $t$. Then $\text{hom}(-,t)$ will spit out a singleton set every time. But there’s no clear way to think of this in a city. What location has only one route to reach it?!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476928/how-do-i-think-of-a-representable-functor ... please could you see this

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I have a busy day today, but I’ll try to come up with something for you.

Comment: Hi! Just reminindg

Comment: I gave it a shot, but once again no promises this is helpful.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I substantially updated my post on the question. It’s long, but I hope it’s helpful. Just letting you know.

Answer (score 4):

I think Joe's answer is really really nice, but for a diversity of perspectives, here is another way to think about "why care about the hom functor"?

Suppose you are given a category $C$ and an object $c\in C$. You are not told what $C$ is, e.g., we do not know if $C$ is a concrete or abstract category. Nor do we know what $c$ is. All we know is the fact that $C$ is a category and $c\in C$. Suppose someone asks you if you can "pick $c$ out of a crowd", i.e., if you have enough information to identify $c$. It seems like we are stuck here. We know nothing about $c$, nor the category $C$ it lives in.

But, wait! We know *something* about $C$. Its a category! So, it has to have morphisms. So, by definition, for any other object $x\in C$, we have a set $C(x,c)$ of morphims into $c$. We can in fact do this for every object in $C$. So this defines a map $ob(C)\to Set$ sending $x\mapsto C(x,c)$.

Now, we still don't know much about $C$ or $c$. We don't really know much about the morphisms of $C$, if the are functions or what. But, we do know *something* about them. They compose! So given any $f\in C(x,c)$ and any $h:y\to x$, we have to have $fh: y \to c$. Hey, this mean we have a map $h^*: C(x,c)\to C(y,c)$! So, we can extend our $ob(C)\to Set$ to a functor $C^{op}\to Set$ by sending any $(f: x\to y)\mapsto f^*:C(y,c)\to C(x,c)$. Thus, we have arrived out our functor $C(-,c)$.

You may be thinking that this does not tell us much about $C$ or $c$. In some sense this is true; we still do not know if $C$ is concrete or abstract or how $c$ was constructed. But, it turns out that we now have all the information we need to "pick $c$ out of a crowd". Hows that? Invoking the yoneda lemma, $C(-,c)$ characterizes $c$ up to isomorphism. That is, if there is some $C(-,x)\cong C(-,c)$, then $x\cong c$. This may not seem like much at first. How important this was did not dawn on me for quite sometime, and I am still appreciating it more each day, but this powerful.

We know nothing about what $C$ is. It could be $Grp$, $Top$, or some weird and abstract category. Nor do we know a lick about $c\in C$. Yet, the structure $C$ has from merely satisfying the definition of a category (which is not a whole lot!) allows us to cook up $C(-,c)$. And this turns out to be enough to essentially define $c$! So maybe we are given another more familiar category $Grp$ and a way to map $F:Grp \to C$. We now have a way (in some sense) to determine if $F(G)\cong c$, for some $G\in Grp$. This in turn gives us (maybe?) enough information to determine if $Grp\simeq C$.

One thing representable functors make me appreciate is how powerful the seemingly simple axioms of category theory are!